# Not using parts of input in C

Tags: c, scanf

I want to get certain values out of an input line in C, but I don't need all of the characters.

I have input lines like this:

```
OUT R1
```

I am only interested in the first character 'O' and the last digit '1'.
I can get these by doing:

```
scanf("%c%c%c R%d\n", &c1, &c2, &c3, &int1);
```

However, I would use memory for c2 and c3 while I won't use them.

Is there a way to not even assign these characters or do I have to discard them manually?

Comment: Are you seriously concerned about two bytes of memory, which probably have automatic storage duration? If so, why don't you simply use `"%*c"`?

Comment: Yes, I would like to produce as slick code as possible. In languages like Python you can use things like anonynous variables and I was wondering if something like that is possible in C too.

Comment: That is indeed what I was looking for, thanks @TWhelan

Comment: I'd like to point out that while your code is a little tighter for not having to declare c2 and c3, your format string will now use a few more bytes so you're not actually saving memory.

Comment: Good point @Richard Schwartz. Thanks for reminding me.